# Bulleted List in WPF RichTextBox shows very small bullets when sent to Outlook

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, richtextbox

I have a Rich Text Box that I am using to create an Email in Outlook, and everything else works great, I convert the RTB text to a byte Array and pass it to the mailItem.RTFBody property and it displays fine in Outlook with the exception of the bullets are very small.  They look fine when I create them in the RichTextBox itself, but somehow in Outlook they become very small, almost impossible to see:

In Outlook:
·   Bullets
·   Are
·   Here

In the RichTextBox:
•   Bullets
•   Are 
•   Here

How can I prevent this from happening?

Current code:

```
oMailItem.RTFBody = GetRTBText();
private byte[] GetRTBText() 
{
    byte[] RTFArr;
    Clipboard.Clear();
    RTBBody.SelectAll();
    RTBBody.Copy();

    RTFArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf));

    return RTFArr;
}
```